# MDX query performance: inconsistent processing times

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am puzzled by strange behavio/performance incosistencies when I run certain MDX query.

The processing times are very inconsistent when I run query for a single member or for two members 'on rows':

The hierarchy has 7 levels: for example, "A" is member on level 6. "A" has 2 children: "X" and "Y".

When I run the MDX with member "X"  ‘On Rows’, it takes two secs.

When I run same MDX for a member "Y" ’On Rows’, it takes 2 secs as well.
If I run same MDX query for both members: {member "X", member "Y"} ‘On Rows’
…. It suddenly takes 2-3 minutes to process this MDX!!

Any possible explanation for this strange behaviour?

### The MDX query looks like this:

```
WITH 
  SET [XL3WithSet0] AS 
    {
      (
        [Measures].[Original Exposure Amount - Drilldown]
       ,[ExpPortfolioType].[ExposurePortfolioType].[All].[COREP - CRD IV].[Standardised]
       ,[PortfolioType].[PortfolioType].[All]
       ,[CRMGroup].[CRMGroup].[All]
       ,[CCFBand].[Hierarchy].[All]
       ,[DrilldownCreditRisk].[InflowOutflowFlag].[All]
      )
    } 
...**********another 25 sets combining [Measures] AND selected dimensions*****
SELECT 
  {
    [XL3WithSet0]
   ,[XL3WithSet1]
   ,[XL3WithSet2]
   ,[XL3WithSet3]
   ,[XL3WithSet4]
   ,[XL3WithSet5]
   ,[XL3WithSet6]
   ,[XL3WithSet7]
   ,[XL3WithSet8]
   ,[XL3WithSet9]
   ,[XL3WithSet10]
   ,[XL3WithSet11]
   ,[XL3WithSet12]
   ,[XL3WithSet13]
   ,[XL3WithSet14]
   ,[XL3WithSet15]
   ,[XL3WithSet16]
   ,[XL3WithSet17]
   ,[XL3WithSet18]
   ,[XL3WithSet19]
   ,[XL3WithSet20]
   ,[XL3WithSet21]
   ,[XL3WithSet22]
   ,[XL3WithSet23]
   ,[XL3WithSet24]
   ,[XL3WithSet25]
  } ON COLUMNS
  --Non Empty   
 ,{
    [DrilldownCreditRisk].[ExposureDrilldown].[All].[Legal Entity 2].[CBRC Repo style MarketParticipant  40089].[Exp No. 14660042].[UNSECURED].[Unsecured - Undrawn Tranche]
   ,[DrilldownCreditRisk].[ExposureDrilldown].[All].[Legal Entity 2].[CBRC Repo style MarketParticipant  40089].[Exp No. 14660042].[UNSECURED].[Unsecured - Drawn Tranche]
  } ON ROWS
FROM [COREP Credit Risk]
WHERE 
  (
    [Time].[Time].[All]
   ,[Scenario].[Scenario].[All]
   ,[ConsolidationProfile].[ConsolidationProfile].[All]
   ,[ExposureType].[ExposureType].[All].[COREP Reporting - CRD IV]
   ,[IntragroupFlag].[IntragroupFlag].[All]
  )
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE;
```

Comment: If you use the [DrilldownCreditRisk].[Level 6] attribute hierarchy members X and Y on rows instead of the [DrilldownCreditRisk].[ExposureDrilldown] hierarchy is it fast (regardless of whether the query returns the same numbers)? Is your hierarchy natural? (Do attribute relationships exist between levels? Do you get a warning at design time about attribute relationships for that hierarchy?)

Comment: It is *probably* because the combination of member X and member Y is creating a lot of *empty* cells. Try wrapping the statement on rows with a `NonEmpty` and THEN a `NON EMPTY`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!

Comment: I did test your suggestions. The problem was the design of the hierarchy- after some research I figured out that hierarchy was not natural, I redesigned the attributes and correctly defined the relationships. Now the mystery is solved and I get consistent processing times on lower levels of the hierarchy.    Thank you again !

Comment: @letecmig great! Glad to help. I made my comment an answer. Would you accept it so others can have that solution suggested to them?

Comment: @GregGalloway as you might have noticed many mdx answers seem to just get forgotten about!

Comment: Maybe the checkmark is not intuitive? Here are some instructions on [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) @letecmig

Answer (score 3):

If you use the [DrilldownCreditRisk].[Level 6] attribute hierarchy members X and Y on rows instead of the [DrilldownCreditRisk].[ExposureDrilldown] hierarchy is it fast (regardless of whether the query returns the same numbers)? Is your hierarchy natural? (Do attribute relationships exist between levels? Do you get a warning at design time about attribute relationships for that hierarchy?) If your hierarchy is unnatural then go to the Attribute Relationships tab and define a [chain](https://intelligentsql.wordpress.com/tag/unnatural-hierarchy/) of attribute relationships that mirrors your hierarchy until the warning icon on your hierarchy goes away.

Performance of natural hierarchies will always be better than unnatural.

Comment: Is a natural hierarchy the same as a user hierarchy?

Comment: A user hierarchy is what I mean by a multi-level hierarchy you define in the middle pane. It has multiple levels as contrasted to an attribute hierarchy which has one level. User hierarchies can be natural or unnatural depending on whether attribute relationships go from level to level. You get a warning icon if it's not natural.

Comment: Thanks Greg - so a user hierarchy is any hierarchy that is not an attribute hierarchy i.e. a user hierarchy is a multi-level hierarchy which can be either natural or unnatural?

Comment: Nice reference you mentioned @GregGalloway!